# Регистрация google play

Tags: android, google-play

При регистрации в google play, google walet спрашивает адрес, индекс...

Я из СНГ, но карта российского банка, следует ли указывать реальные данные, не станет ли это проблемой при регистрации как продавца? Будет ли как-то проверятся введенная информация?

Answer (score 5):

Нет, проблемой это не станет. И указывать стоит реальные данные, поскольку в любой момент вас могут попросить подтвердить указанные данные (открытка с кодом верификации заказным письмом по почте, или же сканы квитанций об оплате коммунальных услуг).

Answer (score -2):

Потрать 140 рублей заведи карту яндекс.деньги или виртуальную киви. А при регистрации акаунта продавца тебе все равно придеться указывать данные твоего банковского счета.